# Simanim are eaten when?

Tags: rosh-hashanah-new-year

When are the Simanim on Rosh HAshanah(symbolic foods) eaten before washing on the Bread or after and at which meal and why?

Comment: [ An Interesting Review of the Whole Halachic topic](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/728283/Rabbi_Avraham_Gordimer/Selected_Minhagim_of_Rosh_Hashana)

Answer (score 2):

[Nitei Gavriel Rosh Hashana 29:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46450&st=&pgnum=219) says that it is a Machlokes whether it should be eaten after the Hamotzi (Tur, Darchei Moshe, Sidur Yaavetz, Sidur Hatanya, Mateh Efraim, Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, Likutei Maharich, etc.) or immediately after Kiddush (Maharil, Ohr Tzadikim, Sidur Rab Shabsai, Ruach Chaim, Ketzei Hamata, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

I've usually seen them eaten after hamotzee on the first night, and often the second night too.

Comment: Are there any sources for these customs meaning and why?

Comment: Why after hamotzee?  I assume because usually we do kiddush then hamotzee.  It sounds from the Gemara like this isn't some spooky ritual thing, rather, eat these foods as part of your meal!  (If I said "we eat turkey on Thanksgiving", would anyone think they take one sliver of turkey, then sit down to their meal of falafel?)  As for why night and not day, night is the first meal of the new year, so most auspicious time for starting things off.  Then second night ... we do everything just like first night.  (And we usually have leftovers ... and why not?)

Answer (score -1):

The simanim are eaten after Motzi, on both nights, but not the day.

Comment: Do you have any sources for your claim?